# Web API v2 Filter checking different types for same field

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have the code below in an API filter.  The `SampleRequester` object is just information from a form.  It has a property called captcha.  It works great but i have other forms that will also have a captcha property.  And this will only work for `SampleRequester` objects.  How could I check any object for a captcha property?

```
public class ValidateCaptcha : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var cookiePayload = actionContext.Request.GetCookie("MyCaptcha");
        SampleRequester requester = (SampleRequester)actionContext.ActionArguments["requester"];
        if(cookiePayload !== requester.captcha)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the possible types in advance, you can use the `as` operator:

```
public class ValidateCaptcha : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var cookiePayload = actionContext.Request.GetCookie("MyCaptcha");
        var requester = actionContext.ActionArguments["requester"] as SampleRequester;
        if (requester != null && cookiePayload == requester.captcha)
             return;
        requester = actionContext.ActionArguments["requester"] as AnotherRequester;
        if (requester != null && cookiePayload == requester.captcha)
             return;

        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
}
```

If you don't, but you expect whatever type to have the property `captcha`, you can use `dynamic`:

```
public class ValidateCaptcha : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var cookiePayload = actionContext.Request.GetCookie("MyCaptcha");
        dynamic requester = actionContext.ActionArguments["requester"];
        if (requester != null && cookiePayload == requester.captcha)
             return;

        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }

}
```

Ideally, the first option, while making sure that all `Requester`s implement the same interface, so you can use `as` to the interface type.

I wonder, why you have the `Captcha` value in the Cookie?

Comment: Where else could I put it?  It's not in plain text I simplified my example because I didn't think that part was actually necessary to answer my question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'where could I put it'? I presented two ways you can look for 'captcha' property on whatever exists in 'requester' actionArgument. Could you please describe better your situation?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use inheritance.  I created a base class called `Form` that has only the captcha property.  Then when in the filter I simply cast the `requester` object to a `Form` object.  The full example can be seen below:

```
public class ValidateCaptcha : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var cookiePayload = actionContext.Request.GetCookie("MyCaptcha");
        Form form = (Form)actionContext.ActionArguments["requester"];
        if(cookiePayload != form.captcha)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }

    }

}
```